# adding Service Worker and IndexedDB types to the eslint config

Tags: typescript, eslint, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, indexeddb

ESLint complains when I'm using types like `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`, `FetchEvent`, `IDBIndexParameters`, `IDBTransactionMode` .,etc to the typescript files while adding PWA setup for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Writing strict typescript for *ServiceWorker* config includes using `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` `FetchEvent`.,etc types in the code. Also to support full PWA architecture one may wanted to support from *IndexedDB* and its types, many will relax typescript and tries to write in javascript and may be relaxes eslint config.

To solve this, add this in your `.eslintrc` file:

1. To support only serviceworker types:

```
  "env": {
    ...
    "serviceworker": true
  },
```

2. To support all standards with typescript install `eslint-config-standard-with-typescript` and config:

```
  "extends": [
    ...
    "standard-with-typescript",
  ]
```